# How to check log.message.format.version in my Apache Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, upgrade

I want to upgrade my Kafka cluster from 2.7 to 2.8. In the upgrade guide, it mentioned to check log format version. How to check this?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify the version it takes the default for that version.
By the way, I recommend you to set the version explicitly.

You can check the version by looking the broker logs when it starts:

```
[2023-11-16 12:07:45,464] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2023-11-16 12:07:48,176] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2023-11-16 12:07:49,031] INFO Registered signal handlers for TERM, INT, HUP (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.LoggingSignalHandler)
[2023-11-16 12:07:49,047] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
...
[2023-11-16 12:07:52,337] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /data/kafka/logdir/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
[2023-11-16 12:07:52,802] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
    advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.134:9092
    alter.config.policy.class.name = null
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
    alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
    ...
    log.message.downconversion.enable = true
    log.message.format.version = 3.0-IV1
    log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
    log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
    ...
```

Regards!